# "in" or "for" as indicators of time in sentences with fronted objects

Tags: prepositions, objects, time-reference, fronting

Which preposition is correct?

> These pictures she painted **for** a month.
>
> These pictures she painted **in** a month.

Comment: Regardless of syntax, ***in** TIMESPAN* and ***for** TIMESPAN* mean different things.

Comment: @StoneyB, could you explain, please?

Comment: *She painted the pictures **in** a month* means she started and finished the paintings during that timespan. ***...for** a month* means that she worked on them during that month, but she may or may not have finished them.

Comment: @StoneyB, well, but the thing is that I've always considered sentences like "she painted these pictures FOR a month" ungrammatical, whereas "she painted these pictures IN a month" - grammatical. I imply that "painted pictures" is telic.

Comment: *painted for a month* would be unusual, but it's easy enough to conceive circumstances when it would be appropriate: "Vera has grandiose ideas but cannot execute. She conceived matched portraits of the Four Horsemen of the Apocalypse, and painted those pictures for a month, then gave up with only the horses' tails completed."

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct but they have different meaning.

> These pictures she painted for a month.

She spent at least a month painting these pictures. She may or may not have finished the job in that time.

> These pictures she painted in a month.

She completed the job of painting the pictures in no more than a month.

(side note: In most contexts, these sentences would sound more natural as "She painted the pictures [in|for] a month.)